# Make Group Row Content Bold in Devexpress DXGrid(Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight-4.0, devexpress

i am doin silveriight 4 app.

i have devexpress grid(v11) below in which grouping is enabled.

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid_labinvestigation" AutoExpandAllGroups="True"  CustomColumnDisplayText="grid_labinvestigation_CustomColumnDisplayText" >
       <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
       <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LabTest" Header="Tests"  MinWidth="150"  />
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LabTestCategory" Header="Test Category" GroupIndex="0" />
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Selected_"  Header="Select" MinWidth="50"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="LabTest_UID" Visible="False" />
         </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
         <dxg:TableView Name="grid_labinvestigation_view"  ShowGroupPanel="False"  />
         </dxg:GridControl.View>
         </dxg:GridControl>
```

I want to make Grouped Column's Content **BOLD**

How can it be done??